# Why curl running from a container complains about local issuer certificate when all the certificates are supposedly present?

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate

Here is my docker command line:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ docker run -v /etc/ssl:/etc/ssl -v /usr/local/share/ca-certificates:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates -v /usr/share/ca-certificates:/usr/share/ca-certificates curlimages/curl -ksvo /dev/null https://registry.yarnpkg.com/csstype/-/csstype-3.0.8.tgz
*   Trying 104.16.19.35:443...
* Connected to registry.yarnpkg.com (104.16.19.35) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [88 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [155 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [6 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [3297 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
{ [264 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [52 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [52 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=registry.yarnpkg.com
*  start date: Apr 29 02:29:46 2023 GMT
*  expire date: May 13 02:29:46 2023 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; ST=California; O=Zscaler Inc.; OU=Zscaler Inc.; CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net) (t)
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* using HTTP/1.x
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /csstype/-/csstype-3.0.8.tgz HTTP/1.1
> Host: registry.yarnpkg.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1-DEV
> Accept: */*
>
{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 05 May 2023 02:17:14 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 175305
< Connection: keep-alive
< CF-Ray: 7c257c694f4253f5-YYZ
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Age: 1689328
< Cache-Control: public, immutable, max-age=31557600
< ETag: "a06dac7944c631c06fa7509c9095ca08"
< Last-Modified: Mon, 19 Apr 2021 07:35:13 GMT
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< Server: cloudflare
<
{ [14612 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host registry.yarnpkg.com left intact
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

This is a corporate network and so we have Zscaler acting as the MITM.

I do not understand why curl is "unable to get local issuer certificate". I can run the same command line on the host machine just fine:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ curl -svo /dev/null https://registry.yarnpkg.com/csstype/-/csstype-3.0.8.tgz
*   Trying 104.16.19.35:443...
* Connected to registry.yarnpkg.com (104.16.19.35) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [88 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Finished (20):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [155 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [6 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [3297 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
{ [264 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [52 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [52 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=registry.yarnpkg.com
*  start date: Apr 29 02:29:46 2023 GMT
*  expire date: May 13 02:29:46 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "registry.yarnpkg.com" matched cert's "registry.yarnpkg.com"
*  issuer: C=US; ST=California; O=Zscaler Inc.; OU=Zscaler Inc.; CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net) (t)
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /csstype/-/csstype-3.0.8.tgz HTTP/1.1
> Host: registry.yarnpkg.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 05 May 2023 02:25:46 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 175305
< Connection: keep-alive
< CF-Ray: 7c2588e75bada216-YYZ
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Age: 1689840
< Cache-Control: public, immutable, max-age=31557600
< ETag: "a06dac7944c631c06fa7509c9095ca08"
< Last-Modified: Mon, 19 Apr 2021 07:35:13 GMT
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< Server: cloudflare
<
{ [14612 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host registry.yarnpkg.com left intact
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

Why do I think curl in the container should work fine? Because I mount all the same certificate directories from the host into the container:

1. /etc/ssl
2. /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
3. /usr/share/ca-certificates

So presumably the container "sees" the same certificates as the host. So why it does not work?

**EDIT 1**

Here is the container run without the `-k` flag:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ docker run -v /etc/ssl:/etc/ssl -v /usr/local/share/ca-certificates:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates -v /usr/share/ca-certificates:/usr/share/ca-certificates curlimages/curl -svvvo /dev/null https://registry.yarnpkg.com/csstype/-/csstype-3.0.8.tgz
*   Trying 104.16.21.35:443...
* Connected to registry.yarnpkg.com (104.16.21.35) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
*  CAfile: /cacert.pem
*  CApath: none
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [88 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [155 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [6 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [3297 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
} [2 bytes data]
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

Comment: Do you know why in yoru first log, there is no `CAfile: /cacert.pem` ?

Comment: Absolutely no idea. Maybe, because `-k` causes curl to skip some logic?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be you passed the option `-k` in docker.

Comment: I passed `-k` on purpose in order to see the result. Not passing it just fails the command.

Comment: When I run your command without `-k` in docker, it worked correctly in corporate environment. Can you paste the log when you run your command without `-k` in docker ?

Comment: I asked the same question on the Linux & Unix forum and got the answer there - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/745432/10009